# Can data of third-party apps synced to Apple Health be retreived via HealthKit

Tags: ios, healthkit, wearables

I am researching the feasibility of an iOS app that can collect data from multiple brands of wearable devices. I am only interested in devices that have apps that are able to sync with Apple Health. Does Apple Health uses HealthKit store to store the data it synced from third-party apps so that I can access it from my iOS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any third-party app *can* save data to Apple Health using the HealthKit APIs, but it's also possible for an app to ignore HealthKit entirely and keep their wearable device data in their own proprietary system. Apple doesn't automatically ingest all third-party health/wearable data into HealthKit.

It's up to the third-party apps to save their data to HealthKit (and for the user to grant permission to these apps to save the data). Your own iOS app will be able to fetch any data that other apps do save to HealthKit (again, assuming the user grants your own app permission to read data). Each HealthKit sample contains a `sourceRevision` property that describes the app/device that generated the sample, and you can display that information to your user, filter your queries by that source, etc.

Comment: So if an app syncs to Apple Health app, is the data stored in to HealthKit? I mean is the data from Apple Health is stored in HealthKit?

Comment: Correct. HealthKit is the data storage and retrieval API for the data that you can see in the Apple Health app. Both iOS/watchOS itself and third-party apps use HealthKit to share this data.

Comment: I'd recommend spending some time reading the overview and "essentials" articles at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit

Comment: @MikeMertsock does that mean if a 3rd party pushes data to HealthKit, i should be able to pull those data as well, like a normal HK entry? or is there an additional step and where can i read about it? 
for a better example: a user has an Oura ring that syncs to Apple Health (activity is in AH), but when we pull AH activities, only those native are pulled, Oura data are ignored.

Comment: Your app can retrieve 3rd party data in exactly the same way, using the same queries and APIs. By default, HealthKit queries will return data from all apps. You can optionally add predicates to the queries to filter for a specific app if needed.